# knowing which item is owned by each customer - spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

lets say I have a table of customers, the contains 2 columns:

1. id
2. preferences array - array of strings, of length 3, might contain nulls. preferences are different for each customer, so one might care about color and the other will not.

as an example:

```
id | preferences array
   |   
-------------------------------------------
1  | {'color:red','shape:triangle','speed:high'}

2  | {'age:14','color:blue',null}
```

I also have a table of items, with again 2 columns. again, id and preferences array - but this time, the array can be of any length:

```
id | preferences array
----------------------------------
   |
1  | {'color:red','shape:triangle','speed:high','hand:third'}
   |
2  | {'shape:circle'}
```

an items is matched to a customer if all of the strings in the customer's preferences appear in the item's preferences array. not all the strings in the item's preferences array has to appear on the customers preferences array, though.

i need to create a new table, in which one of the columns is the customer id, and the other is an array of all of the items id that matched to the customer.

```
customer_id | items
----------------------------------
            |
1           | {3,4,7,300,4190..., 6000}
            |
2           | {3,5617}
.
.
.
19,456      | {1551, 1456,3000}
```

please note that I need a solution that will work even for a lot of items and customers (around 10,000).
how can I do this using SQL (spark sql, specifically)

Comment: what have u tried?

Comment: nothing, I have no idea how to start.

Comment: ok, i need to think on this

Comment: This would be *much* easier if you didn't store values in JSON form but instead had properly normalised tables of customer and item preferences that you could just JOIN to each other.

Comment: not sure what you mean, but since each item can have different number of items in the array, and might have hundreds, I cant just use a different column for each item in the array

Comment: add cardinality of both tables pls.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . One method is to explode the arrays and join.  The following gets the customer/item pairs:

```
select c.id as customer_id, i.id as item_id
from (customers c lateral view
      explode(c.preferences_array) as c_preference
     ) join
     (items i lateral view
      explode(i.preferences_array) as i_preference
     )
     on c_preference = i.preference
group by c.id, i.id, size(c.preferences_array)
having count(*) = size(c.preferences_array);
```

You can reaggregate to get the list of items for each customer.

Note:  This does not return customers with no preferences.  Although they technically meet the requirements of your question, I suspect they don't meet the spirit of what you want to do.